# pycairo install error on osx

Tags: python, macos, pycairo

While I am installing pycairo using easy_install on osx, there is an error message as following:

```
Searching for pycairo
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pycairo/
Reading http://cairographics.org/pycairo
Best match: pycairo 1.10.0
Downloading http://cairographics.org/releases/pycairo-1.10.0.tar.bz2
Processing pycairo-1.10.0.tar.bz2
error: Couldn't find a setup script in /tmp/easy_install-hnheQI/pycairo-1.10.0.tar.bz2
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which OS X do you have? Also, do you have Cairo installed, and, if so, how (homebrew, MacPorts, binary installer from ___ site, manual configure&&make install from source, …)? Meanwhile, have you tried downloading the source package, untarring it, and doing the steps manually?

Comment: I have osx 10.8. I used macport, but it did not work. I've tried all step manually, but nothing happened unfortunately.

Comment: You shouldn't use MacPorts `cairo` with system `python` to try to build `py2cairo`; even if it works, it probably wasn't supposed to work, and you can't rely on it… See my (edited) answer for more.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like pycairo is not set up to be `easy_install`able (or `pip`able).

The first problem is that the PyPI package pycairo points at the Python 3.x version, not the 2.x version (which is called py2cairo) This means you can't `easy_install` or `pip install` it for 2.x. And they don't have a separate py2cairo PyPI package. So, you'd have to explicitly `easy_install http://cairographics.org/releases/py2cairo-1.10.0.tar.bz2`.

The second problem is that the tarball isn't designed to be built with `setuptools`; you have to use `waf`.

So, you're going to have to download the link above (or, better, the latest py2cairo at http://cairographics.org/pycairo/), untar it, and read and follow the INSTALL directions.

This also assumes that you already have Cairo installed properly (e.g., via Homebrew).

PS, not that it would make any difference here, but you really should be using `pip` instead of `easy_install`. The only times you want to use `easy_install` are to install `pip` itself (`sudo easy_install pip`), and to install two or three packages that are `easy_install`able but not `pip`able.

You mentioned that you got Cairo through MacPorts. MacPorts doesn't play well with non-MacPorts. In fact, that's kind of the point: to have a completely isolated set of tools and libraries that can be maintained together. This means if you have MacPorts' `cairo`, you probably want its `py27-cairo`, and `python27` package.

If you want something better integrated with your system, either look for binaries, use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), or build it yourself. (I noticed that Homebrew also has a formula for `py2cairo`, which I believe will install into your system 2.7 Python, but I haven't tested it. Normally, Homebrew doesn't supply Python/Ruby/Perl modules, because you've already got `pip`/`gem`/`cpan`, but they make exceptions for packages that don't work with the standard tools and/or are hard to set up.)